# weblogic application with database

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

Is there any freely available application (war file) for Weblogic where the application uses some kind of database ?

Please redirect me to the correct place to ask this question if this is not the right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install WebLogic with Derby database and examples. There is a MedRec application you can install and use for learning purposes.

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/wls/12c/12_2_1/02-34-004-DeploySampleApplication/deploysampleapplication.html

Google WebLogic MedRec for more articles explaining how to use it.